# adding php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

How can I add php variable to javascript e.g:

```
onClick="javascript:alert('echo $name;')Click Me</a>***
```

but it is not working

i have not includey original becuse it is not showing original …!!

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. What is not working?

Comment: You should have your code snippets enclosed between `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>` to make them easier to read.

Comment: You should add backticks (`) around your code to tell SO to wrap it in a `<code>` block. That way, all code will be shown as you typed it. Check the Markdown editing help for more info.

Comment: It looked better right after it was posted. Looks like an edit messed up the code line.

Comment: Is it just me or is adding PHP to Javascript bad practice?

Answer (score 10):

The php looks fine, as long as the $name variable is set. Try this:

```
onclick="alert('<?php echo $name; ?>');"
```

Comment: Should work :) That's not how I understood the question at first, though ;)

Comment: Make certain the string is JS and HTML safe. htmlspecialchars will do the job for HTML, I've no idea what PHP has for JS though.

Answer (score 1):

Adding PHP variables to javascript can be done simply by using PHP's `<?php` and `?>` open/close tags, like so:

```
<?php $var = 'Hello world!'; ?>
alert('<?php echo $var; ?>');
```

Alternatively, you can echo javascript code, including any vars. However, this is much less readable, and generally considered bad practice:

```
<?php $var = 'Hello world!';
echo "alert('$var');"; ?>
```

**Edit:** The example code you typed is nearly correct; all that you missed are the PHP opening and closing tags, as I used in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Also try this:

```
onclick="var text = '<?php echo $name; ?>'; alert(text);"
```

otherwise unterminated string literal" error appear

Answer (score 0):

another way using short php tags and [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function

```
onclick="alert('<?=str_replace("'", "\'", $name);?>');"
```

In your php.ini short_open_tag must be enabled or use normal approach using echo

```
onclick="alert('<? echo str_replace("'", "\'", $name); ?>');"
```

php.ini code:

```
short_open_tag = On
```